# Angularjs Paypal integration no specific path found to follow

Tags: javascript, angularjs, paypal

I have a web application where the backend is built on `j2ee` and I am using `angularJS` for making the rest calls. My web application has some really complex flows which require payment flow to be seamless. I just cannot find any specific document or example just related to `angularJS` implementation of `Paypal`. Even JavaScript is fine. for now I've used the static JavaScript button but would like to replace it with their `API`. Can somebody guide me through?

Comment: google for `paypal-rest-sdk` and you will get the sdk details.. that should get you started

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Java EE as backend, you might want to use PayPal Java SDK https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK. If you application uses maven as build system, add the following dependency tag into your pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.paypal.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-api-sdk</artifactId>
     <version>LATEST</version>
</dependency>
```

You can refer the following sample app for reference: https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sample-app-java

Comment: I want to implement it using client side technology only i.e. angularjs

Comment: If that is the case, then IIRC PayPal does not have official SDK for it. But you should be able to implement REST API directly using javascript request functions with JSON as the payload